Factor model bond futures
I was reading the Lehman Brother Multifactor Futures Model and there are a few things I don't understand in the way they implement their model.
Firstly, they look at the fitted yields. When they look at the fitted yield does it mean they look at the yield of the $CTD$ bond and then look at the difference between the yield of all the bond in the deliverable basket to the yield of that $CTD$?  So they perform PCA on: $y_{CTD}-y_i$ for all bond $i$ in the deliverable?
They also say in their paper that they are able to model the switch option with this model but I don't understand how. They model the different yields scenarios of the $CTD$  for the last trade date, but shoudn't we instead model all the yield scenarios on the last delivery date since the underlying bonds in the basket can still change in price during that last week of delivery?
Because otherwise the future price doesn't take into account the fact that the CTD can change during that last week, so on the last trade date the future price should be priced at a discount depending on the probability of a CTD switch on that last week, and I don;t see how the model takes this into account as it doesn't model the path of the bonds yield during that last week.
Finally, I don't understand the adjustments made on the different yield scenarios made. I understand that in order to not have an arbitrage opportunity for each bond $i$ we have generated on different yield scenarios $(y_s)_s$ on the last trade date and we should have: $\mathbb{E}[y_s] = FY_i$ (so the expectation of the yields is equal to the forward price of bond $i$). Yet it seems like they do other adjustments related to the implied vol which I don't understand... If we model the yield of the CTD as a normal distribution with mean the forward yield of that CTD and std the implied vol then why any more adjustment is needed?
